# Keep control resource consisting of multiple styles in a single place and use it from there in WPF app

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `DataGrid` with following styles inside `DataGrid.Resources` tag. All I want is to keep it in a single file and get it applied throughout the application for all `DataGrid` controls using a common key.

```
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="DataGridRow.IsSelected" Value="True">                                
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>

                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Somehow I tried to keep it in a separate style file but after that I got confused about how to reference it with a single key as the `SolidColorBrush` tags are outside of the `Style` tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be using the system brushes specifically in your style.
The way to make that re-usable on all datagrid rows is to put it in a resource dictionary. Right click your project in solution manager and add resource dictionary.
Put your common markup in there, something like:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf10">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="DataGridRow.IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

and merge that resource dictionary in app.xaml.

```
<Application x:Class="wpf10.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf10"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application
```

>

Since you have no x:key on the datagridrow style, that will target all datagridrows.

Comment: Hi @Andy, thanks for your time. What you have suggested is somehow useful to manage styles in a different situation. But as you have suggested even if I am putting those styles in a different file and merging it, it still doesn't target the DataGridRow with those SolidColorBrush, so I came up with a solution to target DataGridRow BackGround color instead.